# Why STATE_RINGING instead of CALL_OFFHOOK

Tags: android

This is what supposed to be happening. But my app is recording for the very first time I'm making a call. After that, whenever I'm calling, the phone goes on RINGING state. I put a Log.i() statement for all the states so that I may get the phone state every time it changes. Every time I'm making a call, the phone goes on RINGING state.

Comment: I don't have understood the problem.... Please write steps you do, for example: (1) start a call, (2) phone state is "ringing", (3) etc... I this way I understand what you're doing....

Comment: This is what supposed to be happening. But my app is recording for the very first time I'm making a call. After that, whenever I'm calling, the phone goes on OFFHOOK state. I put a Log.i() statement for all the states so that I may get the phone state every time it changes. Every time I'm making a call, the phone goes on OFFHOOK state after End call phone goes in IDLE state.

Comment: i Want when the is RINGING  then it go on RINGING state after pic the call it goes on OFFHOOK state

Comment: I'm trying and when a call is ringing I got RINGING and when I answer to it the state became OFFHOOK. Then hanging-up returns to IDLE state. If there is a current active call and a second call arrives, the state will be RINGING.

Comment: can u please share me code

Comment: @emandt can u please share me